# question about VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features

Tags: c++, vulkan

I ran into an issue when adding features to a physical device using bootstrap https://github.com/charles-lunarg/vk-bootstrap. Doing so gives me assertion failed
`Assertion failed: m_init, file \vkbootstrap\VkBootstrap.h, line 132`

I understand that this could indicate a bug within the vk-bootstrap source, but I wanted to rule out that it's my own fault. Here is the code snippet which im using to add (empty)`VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features` into physical device and I wanted to know if I'm intializing it correctly

```
    VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features feat;
    feat.pNext = nullptr;
    feat.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_VULKAN_1_2_FEATURES;

    vkb::PhysicalDeviceSelector selector{ vkb_inst };
    vkb::PhysicalDevice physicalDevice = selector
        .set_minimum_version(1, 2)
        .set_surface(_surface)
        .set_required_features_12(feat)
        .select()
        .value();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking Results for errors.

Probably should be something like:

```
vkb::PhysicalDeviceSelector selector{ vkb_inst };
auto maybe_device = selector.select();
if( !maybe_device ) panic( maybe_device.error() );

vkb::PhysicalDevice device = maybe_device.value();
```

Comment: im getting `no_suitable_device` error regardless if i use my nvidia geforce 1050 ti or integrated graphics, and even adding ancient features causes that error

Comment: i found solution,
`VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures feat;` -> `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures feat{};`, error checking helped alot